# Local storage is null on new tab

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have an asp.net eshop and I decided to add a recently viewed items functionality using localStorage.
Opening a product page the item is added in an array and saved in localStorage.

The problem is that when I open a product on a new tab the localStorage is empty and therefore the item is not saved in the original array.

Items that I open on the same tab are correctly registered in localStorage and closing and reopening the browser displays the saved items.

Thanks for your help in advance!

```
 var currentItems = localStorage.getItem("CBRecentlyViewed");
 currentItems = JSON.parse(currentItems);
 if (currentItems == null) {
   currentItems = new Array();
 } 
 var currentItem = { prodID: getQuerystring("productID") };
 currentItems.push(currentItem);
 localStorage.setItem('CBRecentlyViewed', JSON.stringify(currentItems));
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Is the same behavior happening in all browsers? Can we see a part of the code?

Comment: Hi Dan. Tried it on chrome and firefox. this is the code that adds a product in the array (stripped some extra code)
var currentItems = localStorage.getItem("CBRecentlyViewed");
            currentItems = JSON.parse(currentItems);

            if (currentItems == null) {
                currentItems = new Array();
            }
            var currentItem = {
                prodID: getQuerystring("productID")
                };
            currentItems.push(currentItem);

localStorage.setItem('CBRecentlyViewed', JSON.stringify(currentItems));